# Spring MCV 3 showErrors doesn't display anything

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity

I try to validate a simple form. The validation is well executed but the result page doesn't display the errors.
I use velocity to render the page. 
I've used as example the PetClinic project from spring website.

Here is my controller when I hit the "post form" button:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/subscription")
public class SubscriptionController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/newCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute Customer customer, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

    new CustomerValidator().validate(customer, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "subscription";
    }
    else {
        status.setComplete();
        return  "redirect:/admin";
    }
}

}
```

When I go in debug, I see the errors. I'm successfully redirected on the subscription page but the errors are not displayed.

My webpage (simplified):

```html
...

            #springBind("customer")
            #springShowErrors("<br/>" "")
            <form class="form-horizontal"  method="post" action="#springUrl("/subscription/newCustomer/")">

                        ....

                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="controls">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">#springMessage("website.subscription.signup")</button>
                        </div>

             </form>

 ...
```

if you need anything else, don't hesitate to tell me. Thanks for your help! I'm stuck on this since several days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :** 
I finally found the error. It was with the springBind tag. I didn't well understand that you need to bind the field to show the associated error. Here is the fixed code for one field for twitter bootstrap framework.

```html
                    #springBind("customer.name")
                    <div class="control-group   #if(${status.error})error#end">

                        <!-- Prepended text-->
                        <label class="control-label">#springMessage("website.subscription.name")</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <div class="input-prepend">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                                 <input class="input-xlarge"
                                    placeholder="John Doe" id="name" name="name" type="text">                                   
                            </div>
                            <p class="help-block">                                  
                                #springShowErrors("<br/>" "")
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

springShowErrors(...) will show all the errors associated with the field name of the POJO customer.